# How to build a web site which gives a sub-domain dynamically to every registered user?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create subdomain upon user registration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841006/create-subdomain-upon-user-registration)

Suppose I have a site, and I wish to give a sub-domain for each registered users.
Like my site, `http://site.com/`.

And the `test-user` is a user registered on my site, and the site wants to make a sub-domain for that user.

Like `http://test-user.site.com`.

Like `http://test-user1.site.com` for test-user1.

I hope you understood the requirement. How can I create a sub-domain using my sites back-end
or dynamically while registering?

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806313/create-subdomain-per-user and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841006/create-subdomain-upon-user-registration

Comment: @Paolo it's not really a dupe IMO.

Comment: @Pekka: It kind of is, because ultimately that's what he has to end up doing. Can you imagine how much space he would be wasting if he added subdomain records for every single user that created an account?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, nothing but this has nothing to do with that!

Comment: @animuson @Paolo you're right, my concern was more that the ways described are horribly performance-intensive.

Answer (score 6):

1. make a DNS record to bring * requests to the site IP.
2. set up a web server to handle * requests too (thanks @animuson for mentioning)
3. check $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] against database.
4. Profit!!!

Comment: You forgot to mention modifying the VirtualHost for the domain to catch those * requests being brought to the IP.

Comment: This is terrible for performance - every request for every resource has to be run through PHP this way. Not a good option for real-world use IMO (although all the alternatives I can think of involve fiddling with the server's `VirtualHost` configuration and are often impossible).

Comment: Who orders you to request from this subdomain any resource other than html, @Pekka ?

Comment: @Pekka: You can always specify certain subdomains that will go directly to certain files or folders and skip PHP, as long as they are defined before the wildcard VirtualHost in the configuration. That's how I run my site. Apache directs everything to my index.php file, except for the resource subdomains for css, images, scripts, etc which all go directly to their respective folders.

Comment: @Col @animuson this method is fine as long as you yourself are the only people running the site. The OP, however, is looking to set up a site for each of his users, who are unlikely to be willing to share a resources folder.

Comment: @Pekka I can't see in the question any sign of the OP's intention to become an ISP for his users. However it can be issue too.  But the general use is just to substitute site.com/user with user.site.com and there is no problem in such case

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a lot simpler than it seems. The first thing you're going to do is setup a wildcard dns entry, which will send all traffic to for those subdomains to your site. Without this all of your subdomains will be unreachable.

From there you have a few different options-

Through your webserver configurtion (virtual host, .htaccess file, whatever) you can direct different subdomains internally to different folders.

You could also use a script and check against the request itself ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] in php) to find the subdomain, and then do whatever customization you need that way.