# Redirecting to a subdomain from another domain without changing its URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, blogs, redirect

I have a project where users can create their own profiles. And the profiles will have sub-domain URLs like `robert.blogger.com`. So if that user has some domain of his own like `robert.com`. 
Then I want every request for `robert.com` to redirect to `robert.blogger.com` without changing the URL.

The URL should show `robert.com/home.html`, `robert.com/aboutus.html` etc. but actually code should be run from `robert.blogger.com/index.html`, `robert.com/aboutus.html` etc.

Is this possible? If so, how can this be done?

Comment: ServerName robert.blogger.com; ServerAlias robert.com

Comment: You want someone else his website to run from yours?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create subdomain per user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806313/create-subdomain-per-user), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116898/how-do-i-create-personal-sub-domain-programmatically-with-php, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12408582/virtual-subdomain-one-subdomain-per-user, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586129/create-subdomains-on-the-fly-with-htaccess-php, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183928/how-to-let-php-to-create-subdomain-automatically-for-each-user

Comment: @ mikeB that question has no relation with this??

Comment: @IamLitto They all talk about what you're asking for. You realize that the owner of robert.com is going to have to log into his DNS management tool and point his domain at your servers. There's no way for you to hijack his domain (for good reason). If you're unaware of all this you need to start by learning about the basics of DNS and apache configs.

Comment: @mike B hey.. man... this is not hijacking & all... I will get that authority to point his domain to my server. Just forget about all these things,.. please say how can I acheive this by coding or any other settings???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domainname.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.domainname.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) user/user.php?username=%1
ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.php
IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not done with php.

The best way to accomplish this is via an HTACCESS redirect. Alternatively this can be done via a DNS A record, but would require elevated access.

place a file named (.htaccess) in the root directory of the domain that contains the following:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule * subdomain.domain.com [L]

Comment: I have a server with dedicated IP. Can you please advice how to redirect some domain to this server using DNS A record??

Answer (score 0):

Not possible in php unless you use curl. 
You need to setup a wildcard DNS
record to catch all subdomains and send
them to you web server.
Then you need to setup Apache to catch
all named virtual hosts and send it to a
directory.

Answer (score 0):

I would just the [header](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function.
    header("Location: http://"$user_name."blogger.com");

Comment: I do not want a redirection.. I want something other else..pls read the question once agin...